# Rails + MySQL: How to decrease sleep process's time out?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, timeout

When I run 'show processlist;', then I get so many sleep processes.

[result of 'show processlists'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/calhY.png)

I set wait_timeout and interactive_timeout to 60 in my.cnf. But, sleep process is not died when time 60 on processlist. I found that sleep process is died when time is 7900. What happend?? How can I decrease sleep process's time out?

If you need other information, I will give information as I possible.

**UPDATE**

I use root, read_only and deploy account on mysql. And I found root and read_only accounts run correct. Query -> Sleep -(60sec)-> release process.

But deploy account, using to connect between rails server and mysql, run wrong. Query -> Sleep -(7900sec)-> release.  So, I think that deploy account or Rails is problem. However, I dont have any idea to fix this.

Comment: Although rather old, please refer to the following answer that describes MySQL rails gem wait_timeout functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796133/mysql-not-respecting-wait-timeout-setting-in-my-cnf

Answer (score 0):

If you added those values to your /etc/my.cnf you need to restart MySQL for them to take effect.

You can change them interactively with these commands

```
SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout = 180;
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = 180;
```

Note that existing connections will not pick up the new values, they will timeout at a time based upon the settings when they were created.

Comment: Thank you, but I was already restart mysql and I check this "show global variables like '%time%';". But, sleep processes is not died at setting time